# Rails - accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Movie Model and an Actor Model:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :poster, PosterUploader

  has_many :actors

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :actors

end


class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :movie

end
```

The Movie controller:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_movie, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
  end

  def show
    @movie.actors.build
  end

  def new
    @movie = Movie.new
    @movie.actors.build
  end

  def create
    @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)
    if @movie.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Movie Successfully Created'
      redirect_to movie_path(@movie)
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = 'Invalid Movie Form'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
.
.
.
  private

  def set_movie
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  end

  def movie_params
    params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :genre, :description, :duration, :release, :poster, actors_attributes: [:name])
  end

end
```

and the show view:

```
<div id="show_movie_container">
  <p><%= image_tag(@movie.poster_url, size: "300x400") %></p>
  <p><%= @movie.title %> (<%= @movie.release %>)</p>
  <p><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_movie_path %> | <%= link_to 'Delete', movie_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are You sure you want to delete this movie?' } %></p>
  <p>Duration: <%= @movie.duration %></p>
  <p>Genre: <%= @movie.genre %></p>
  <p>Actors: <%= @movie.actors.name %></p>
  <p>Description: <%= @movie.description %></p>
</div>
```

The problem is every time I try to display the Actors on the view, I keep getting 'Actors: Actor' instead of the name I typed in when I submitted the form. When I look at my server logs I don't understand where the "0" is coming from in the actors_attributes hash:

```
"actors_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Christian Bale"}}
```

Not sure if that has anything to do with the problem.

When I go into the console and type 'm = Movie.last', and then type 'm.actors' I can successfully get back:

```
#<Actor:0x007fcd2890ab58> {
                 :id => 9,
               :name => "Christian Bale",
                :bio => nil,
        :filmography => nil,
         :created_at => Wed, 09 Sep 2015 16:02:55 UTC +00:00,
         :updated_at => Wed, 09 Sep 2015 16:02:55 UTC +00:00,
           :movie_id => 9
    }
```

Just can't get the same back in the view.

I've been stuck on this for a couple hours and would greatly appreciate any help provided, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, you need to ***iterate*** through `@movie.actors` like below and display the actors name

```
<% @movie.actors.each do |actor| %>
  <p>Actors: <%= actor.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks Pavan. Do you have any idea why i'm getting two <p>Actors</p> tags now in my view? Very strange.

Comment: @Banner Its not strange. It is because I kept it inside the do loop. If you want a single Actors, place it above the do loop.